# Transfer spring properties file to Database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Can we read the property values from the DB instead of setting up it on `application.properties` ? or even can we update the property value from code if a default value is set up in the `application.properties` file

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [Spring Cloud Config Server](https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/).
The spring context is initialized with the values from `application.properties` to which your database config belongs as well. You would need to establish the database connection prior to constructing the whole application context and then reading properties from the database. This can probably be achieved by modifiying how Spring works, but I'd rather recommend using a means officially supported by Spring.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But can point to an example for the same or can you let me know what official means you are talking about